# How to group by multilple columns to a list and maintain order?

Tags: group-by, pyspark

I am trying to group by two different columns but sort the grouped elements by timestamp and running into some issues.

Initial dataframe:

```
| user_id|group_id|item_id|value|timestamp|
+--------+--------+-------+-----+---------+
|  A     |1.0     |1      |5    |100      | 
|  A     |1.0     |2      |6    |90       | 
|  A     |0.0.    |3      |7    |80       |
|  A     |0.0.    |4      |8    |80       |
+---+----+--------+-------+-----+----------
```

What I want:

```
| user_id|group_id|grouped_item_value|timestamps|
+--------+--------+------------------+----------+
|  A     |1.0     |[[2,6],[1,5]]     |[90,100]  |
|  A     |0.0     |[[4,7],[3,8]]     |[80,80]   |
```

The grouped_item_value column is sorted in descending order based on the second value in the tuple.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've been banging my head against a wall for 9 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = (
    df.withColumn("item_value", F.array(F.col("item"), F.col("value")))
    .orderBy("timestamp")
    .groupby(["user_id", "group_id"])
    .agg(F.collect_list(F.col("item_value")), F.collect_list("timestamp"))
)
```

1. First you create an array of `item` and `value` pairs.
2. Then sort the dataframe by `timestamp`
3. Then you groupby `user_id` and `group_id` to `collect_list()` for `item_value` and `timestamp`